# Regex expression for getting e mail fields without domain

Tags: regex, email, elasticsearch

I have an email address like `example.regex@yahoo.com`. Is there a regex expression that will match `example.regex@yahoo.com`, `example.regex`, `example`, `regex`? The expression should not match `Yahoo.com`, `Yahoo` or `com`

Have the following e-mail address:
denisa.example@yahoo.com and I want the following strings to match the query:

```
denisa.example
denisa
example
```

I already tried it with the following elastic-search analyzer query:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "email": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": true,
                    "patterns": [
                        "([^@]+)",
                        "(\\p{L}+)",
                        "(\\d+)",
                        "@(.+)"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "email": {
                    "tokenizer": "uax_url_email",
                    "filter": [
                        "email",
                        "lowercase",
                        "unique"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but it gives me the following results:

```
denisa.example
denisa
example
yahoo.com
yahoo
com
```

I found an answer :

```
"patterns" : [ 
                 "^(.*?)@",
            "(\\w+(?=.*@))"].
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give examples of what kind of result do you expect? Do you want to match everything at once? Match groups separated by dots? Match just the left part of the @?

Comment: Yep i will add now

Comment: I updated the description :)

Comment: @MikaelMayer, yes, the left part, for the left part example.regex, example,regex.

Comment: So the input are `denisa.example@yahoo.com` and `denisa`, and you want a function that returns `true`, even if the second example is `denisa.example@yahoo.com`, `denisa.example` or `example`, correct? But it should return `false` if the second string is `yahoo`, `yahoo.com` or `com`, correct?

Comment: yep, but i want this to be written in regular expression, cuz i am using it for the elasticsearch analyzer

Comment: "settings" : {
      "analysis" : {
         "filter" : {
            "email" : {
               "type" : "pattern_capture",
               "preserve_original" : true,
               "patterns" : [
                  "([^@]+)",
                  "(\\p{L}+)",
                  "(\\d+)",
                  "@(.+)"
               ]
            }
         },
         "analyzer" : {
            "email" : {
               "tokenizer" : "uax_url_email",
               "filter" : [ "email", "lowercase",  "unique" ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```js
function extract(email) {
  const name = email.match(/^(.*?)@.*/)[1];
  return [
    name,
    ...name.split(".")
  ]
}

console.log(extract("example.regex@yahoo.com"));
```

If you check your browser console, you will print something like that:

`(3) ["example.regex", "example", "regex"]`

Comment: This only works for example.regex, but that i have already achieve, i also need that example and regex to match the expression. But thanks

Comment: In which case it doesn't work ? It should works for every email.

Comment: It doesnt match example, neither regex.

Comment: I want a expression that matches example.regex, example, regex. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately i use it in elasticsearch and i cannot add function.. maybe I can exclude somehow the @yahoo.com, yahoo, com. Something like: "^(@(.*?)\\.)" ?Thanks